# Laravel 5 response not triggering $.ajax({success})

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, http, laravel

I have an ajax request with jQuery, the form submits, the controller responds accordingly ant does all the login logic, but the $.ajax success function doesn't trigger. The error function does get triggered, in two cases. The validation fails or the user typed the password wrong.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

The code for the ajax call:

```
(function() {
var submitAjaxRequest = function(e) {

    var form = $(this);

    var method = form.find('input[name="_method"]').val() ||  'POST';

    $.ajax({

        type: method,

        url: form.prop('action'),

        data: form.serialize(),

        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if( data.status === 200 ) {//redirect if not authenticated user.
                $( location ).prop( 'pathname', 'projects' );
                var errors = data.responseJSON;
                console.log(data.responseJSON);
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            if( data.status === 401 ) {//redirect if not authenticated user.
                $( location ).prop( 'pathname', 'auth/login' );
                var errors = data.responseJSON;
                console.log(data.responseJSON);
            }
            if( data.status === 422 ) {
            //process validation errors here.
            var errors = data.responseJSON; 

            errorsHtml = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul>';

            $.each( errors , function( key, value ) {
                errorsHtml += '<li>' + value[0] + '</li>'; 
            });
            errorsHtml += '</ul></di>';

            $( '#form-errors' ).html( errorsHtml ); 
            } else {

            }
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
};

$('form[data-remote]').on('submit', submitAjaxRequest);
})();
```

And the method that handles the post request:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials))
    {
        return response(array('msg' => 'Login Successfull'), 200)
          ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }

    return response(array('msg' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage()), 401)
          ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using:

```
<button type="submit" onsubmit="validate()" >

function validate()
{
  ajax call; // it was supporting html5 validation
}
```

Then I used:

```
<button type="button" onclick="validate()" >

function validate()
{
  ajax call; // here it was not supporting html5 validation 
             //but working for success and error part
}
```